# How can i give multiple objects a vertex color attribute?

Tags: vertices, color

I'm trying to export from blender into houdini and keep the color attribute, I've found adding a Color attribute in the "Object data properties" and then baking the color works great but i can't seem to be able to add the color attribute to all the objects in my scene without doing it 1 by 1.

I've attached an image of the attribute i'm talking about so any help with adding that to all selected (or all objects in general) would be great.

I've tried holding Alt when adding it but it still only adds it to the last selected mesh[image]

Comment: maybe this add-on helps you? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcegkL96CQo

Comment: Could you just add the detail: what you're baking _from_ , to vertex color?